# Confusion about what exactly a rational function on an integral scheme does

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be an integral scheme of finite type over an arbitrary field $k$. I am interpreting rational functions on $X$ as elements of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X, \eta}$ at the generic point $\eta$ of $X$. Does this rational function somehow determine a morphism from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{1}$? If so, how?

Comment: Unwind the definitions: an element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is a regular function on an open subset $U$ containing $\eta$, so...

Comment: So it certainly gives a rational morphism to $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ basically by definition. But can it be extended to those closed subsets where it has a pole? The reason for asking is trying to understand rational equivalence of cycles from Fulton's Intersection Theory. There it is claimed that a dominant morphism from a variety $V$ to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ determines a rational function on $V$.

Comment: Or perhaps if you just had a reference that explains in detail the relationship between the two definitions of rationally equivalent cycles? I'm finding Fulton seems to assume a lot.

Comment: That sounds like good context to edit in to your question. The extension issue has been covered before on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145136/rational-function-and-morphisms-of-quasiprojective-varieties) among other places. The dominant claim is very straightforward: a dominant rational map between integral schemes $X$ and $Y$ gives a field extensions $K(Y)\to K(X)$, and as $K(\Bbb P^1)=k(t)$, there's an obvious choice for what rational function to pick.

Comment: Thank you, I will look t some other questions before making any edits. Could you recommend a book that would get me up to speed on what I would need for Fulton? I seem to be in the target audience as someone who has done most of Hartshorne chapters 2 and 3, but I am finding there is still a big gap.